# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null (Image in jar file)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, stream, bitmapfactory

I am trying to trade images over from Unity3d to java.

From Unity I am sending:

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, scene.thumbnail.name + ".jpg");
```

This returns the following path in Android (seen via log.i):

```
jar:file:///data/app/com.package.name/base.apk!/assets/image_1.jpg
```

I am now trying to decode this image into a bitmap:

```
 InputStream stream =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/assets/image_1.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
```

However, bitmap is always null. What am I missing? Am I referring to the wrong path? How can I tell java to decode the file in the path unity is providing?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :)

I had to use the AssetManager:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream stream;

try {

            stream = assetManager.open(imagePathList.get(i));

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

            if (bitmap != null)
                imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            return null;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what imagePathList.get(i) returns? Is it the absolute path as `jar:file:///data/app/com.package.name/base.apk!/assets/image_1.jpg` or just `assets/image_1.jpg` ?